# What is the antonym of "saturation"?

Tags: word-request

Hello My fellow ELLians,

I am looking for a noun which describes the antonym of ***saturation*** the best.

For instance, this noun can be a word that conveys the state of being fully drained.

Any suggestion or recommendations is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for sth like lethargy?

Comment: @AIQ thanks for your comment, but, no, I am looking for something like "totally Emptied" like the exact opposite of " something being full to the point of overflowing"

Comment: Umm nothing comes to mind but *void*.

Comment: I just came up with "exhaustion", still I am looking forward to your comments my friends. I think "exhaustion" works fine.

Comment: Coming at it from another angle, "innocence" or "virginity". Or, "devoid" (an adjective, but...).

Comment: Scarcity, paucity, hunger. Parchedness, aridity.